# Two expressions of KdV Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have seen two expressions of KdV Equation:

> $$u_t-6uu_x+u_{xxx}=0$$
>   $$u_t+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0$$

Are they the same? How can I transform one from another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $v = -6 u$, then $v_t + v v_x + v_{x x x} = -6 (u_t - 6 u u_x + u_{xxx})$.